# Is it safe to update my Samsung Galaxy Neo to KitKat?

Tags: updates, 4.4-kitkat, samsung, android-versions

The Samsung Galaxy Neo is officially receiving a KitKat update, which is supposed to bring fixes and performance improvements. Will I experience any problems if I update to the latest version, like lag, shutdown problems or battery issues?

Answer (score 0):

These so called updates are meant to fix bugs, errors etc and improve performance of the devices. So if you update the phone you will experience better performance. There is nothing to worry. Also updates includes a lot of security fixes which keeps you away from online attacks.